# Windows 10 - accessing monitor A's content from only monitor B

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I have a 4-monitor setup. Monitors #1,#2,#3 are in my office, and monitor #4 is in my bedroom. Monitor #1 is main. Monitors #2,#3,#4 are extended.

My problems are:
i) In either room, I am often unable to access a window that has been opened on a monitor in the other room. I would have to guess blindly grab the window with my mouse without seeing it.
ii) In the bedroom, I am unable to see start menu functionality or open, e.g. an icon from the taskbar. While I could blindly press [Windows]+[program name]+[enter], for some programs I need to actually start them with a right-click (e.g., safe mode, admin mode, etc).

The optimal solution would be any of the following, preferred in their given order:
a) Extend monitor #1 to #2 and #3 and duplicate #1 to #4.
b) Any option that lets me "roll" my screens. I.e., #1,#2,#3,#4 swap pairwise their imagery with #2,#3,#4,#1.
c) Any option that lets me view what is on a different screen and grab what is on that screen with my mouse in order to pull it on my visually accessible monitor.

I am unable to figure out whether or how any of these solutions are possible in Windows 10.
Regardless, please help me by presenting any solution that can readily configured, if need be by virtue of a suitable program.

Comment: Perhaps setting "Show my taskbar on all displays" in *Settings > Personalization > Taskbar* will help.

Comment: @harrymc Nice! I did not think of that. It works "half", because the windows key does only open the menu on the main display. And [Alt]+[Tab] still only shows all applications on the main screen. It is a pitty that one seems to not be able to duplicate displays AND extend displays in windows.

Comment: That's the only useful feature I could think of.

Comment: How about a screen recording program? Are there any that show a preview of all displays in a little window? This way, I could use the preview to steer my mouse less blindly.

Comment: Try Task View (I can't test myself - only one monitor here).

Comment: @harrymc: Task View is an interesting idea. I did not know that it was the same as what I get when pressing [Windows] + [Tab]. As you say you could not know, but in fact task view shows on each display a different set of open windows -- namely only those that are opened on the respective monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You preferred solution "a) Extend monitor #1 to #2 and #3 and duplicate #1 to #4." should be possible.

At least on my setup (laptop with two attached screens), I can have the primary screen duplicated plus an extension screen:

https://i.imgur.com/QAPgrc6.png

https://i.imgur.com/zNcOKnU.png

(sorry, not enough reputation to embed images yet)